# Purpose of deleting internal PAD

Tags: layout, isolation, routing

I just learned today that, when you're routing the board you can delete the pad of through hole connectors on the internal layout. Some company even ask to delete all the internal pad that are not used.

I was wondering, what is the purpose of deleting all the unused internal pad? Is that for the isolation? Is there any possibilities to have problems with non used internal pads?

Answer (score 3):

So two schools of thought on this.   One removing the internal pads can increase yield for the PCB process.  It gives them a lot more clearance around the holes they're going to drill for instance.  Also pcb houses feel it extends their drill life not having to drill through all that copper each time.

On the SI side of things if you're trying to build a controlled impedance via structure, having all these internal pads doesn't help so another reason to remove them.   You might also remove them if you plan to back drill.

On the other side of things some people, and military standards, believe that leaving the pads there helps strengthen the via structure itself and improve long term mechanical reliability.

Personally I remove them.